# Imported character from ROBLOX as .obj doesn't show up

Tags: modeling

I am making a Roblox graphic and whenever I open blender and delete the cube and then I tried to import my OBJ of the Roblox character, but it didn't show up.

I've been dealing with this issue for about 1-2 months now.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever models don't import correctly I usually try different formats, different programs or try converting them in [Noesis](https://richwhitehouse.com/index.php?content=inc_projects.php) (Handy model conversion program).
If I can't get the model this way then I usually figure the file is completely broken and should obtain it from elsewhere.